Migrate Projections&quote from Hibernate 5.X to Hibernate 6.X?
I know there are a lot of topics on this already but certain areas I haven't been able to find how I should perform the migration. Specifically I'm having issues with Projections and Restrictions.sqlRestriction.
Given the example stubs below, how would I go about transforming them to valid 6 syntax?
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("foo > bar"));

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("a.foo"), "foo");

